# Seleccionar archivo mas reciente xlsx

Tags: php, mysql, excel, phpexcel

Buen dia tengo el siguiente codigo para importar la informacion de un excel a mysql a una tabla especifica mi pregunta es como puedo hacer que seleccione el archivo mas reciente.

Los pongo en contexto en una carpeta compartido suben un archivo cada hora en el cual vienen todos los registros de produccion lo que quiero es ingresar esos datos a una base de datos y asi poder mostrar en una pagina web toda la produccion por hora.\

```
# Cargar clases instaladas por Composer
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

# Nuestra base de datos
require_once "bd.php";

# Indicar que usaremos el IOFactory
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory;

# Obtener conexión o salir en caso de error, mira bd.php
$bd = obtenerBD();

# El archivo a importar
$rutaArchivo = "Reports/ASSOCIATE_SCANNING_REPORT_20220725060005.xlsx";
$documento = IOFactory::load($rutaArchivo);

# Se espera que en la primera hoja estén los productos
$hojaDeScanning = $documento->getSheet(0);

# Preparar base de datos para que los inserts sean rápidos
$bd->beginTransaction();

# Preparar sentencia de productos
$sentencia = $bd->prepare("insert into scanning_report
(Warehouse,Zone,From_Sc,To_Sc,User_Name_Sc,Date_Sc,Material_Number_Sc,Serial_Number,Quantity,Description) values
(?, ?, ? ,?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? )");

# Calcular el máximo valor de la fila como entero, es decir, el
# límite de nuestro ciclo
$numeroMayorDeFila = $hojaDeScanning->getHighestRow(); // Numérico
$letraMayorDeColumna = $hojaDeScanning->getHighestColumn(); // Letra
# Convertir la letra al número de columna correspondiente
$numeroMayorDeColumna = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate::columnIndexFromString($letraMayorDeColumna);

// Recorrer filas; comenzar en la fila 2 porque omitimos el encabezado
for ($indiceFila = 2; $indiceFila <= $numeroMayorDeFila; $indiceFila++) {

    # Las columnas están en este orden:
    $warehouse = $hojaDeScanning->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $indiceFila);
    $zone = $hojaDeScanning->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $indiceFila);
    $from = $hojaDeScanning->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $indiceFila);
    $to = $hojaDeScanning->getCellByColumnAndRow(4, $indiceFila);
    $userName = $hojaDeScanning->getCellByColumnAndRow(5, $indiceFila);
    $dateTime = $hojaDeScanning->getCellByColumnAndRow(6, $indiceFila);
    $materialNumber = $hojaDeScanning->getCellByColumnAndRow(7, $indiceFila);
    $serialNumber = $hojaDeScanning->getCellByColumnAndRow(8, $indiceFila);
    $quantity = $hojaDeScanning->getCellByColumnAndRow(9, $indiceFila);
    $description = $hojaDeScanning->getCellByColumnAndRow(10, $indiceFila);
    $sentencia->execute([$warehouse, $zone, $from, $to, $userName, $dateTime, $materialNumber, $serialNumber, $quantity, $description]);
}

# Hacer commit para guardar cambios de la base de datos
$bd->commit();
```

El problema para subir el archivo es que los archivos que estan en la carpeta compartida aparecen con un nombre predefinido y la fecha en que se compartio espero me puedan ayudar a resolver este problema

Answer (score 1):

Existen multiples tecnologias alternas para esto:

***1. metodo:*** si no requieres que sea un usuario quien haga la importancion del archivo; yo suelo implementar interfaces automatizadas con la herramienta `incron` [Link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Incron_(Espa%C3%B1ol))

Esta herramienta me permite monitorear eventos en el file system cuando un archivo se mueve de un lugar a otro o es creado... incluso con un [cron job](https://blog.desdelinux.net/cron-crontab-explicados/?utm_source=destacado-inside) cada X tiempo tambien se puede pero eso es otra tecnologia; ambos se emplean con el mismo objetivo al cunplirce el criterio se ordena la ejecucion de un script por cli.

***2. metodo:*** En cuanto a la ejecucion del script que hace el trabajo fuerte seria el siguiente: \

```php
$files = scandir('data', SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING);
$newest_file = $files[0];
```

***Nota:*** 
hago la aclaracion, que `SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING` no ordena Date Time o timestamp; en realidad hace un ordenamiento alfabetico; segun el `filename`; si haces una correcta implementacion y tus archivos tiene el nombre con la fecha en un orden adecuado para este script puede funcionarte correctamente.

***3. metodo:***  El que uso personalmente es mediante este script el cual implementa `filemtime`, a diferencia que los dos metodos anteriores este no depende del nombre del archivo; ya que simplemente valida la fecha en que se modifico por ultima vez el/los archivos:

```php
<?php

$str_path = '/PATH/';

$cls_rii =  new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator( $str_path ),
    \RecursiveIteratorIterator::CHILD_FIRST
);

$ary_files = array();

foreach ( $cls_rii as $str_fullfilename => $cls_spl ) {
    
    if($cls_spl->isFile())
    {
        $ary_files[] = $str_fullfilename;
    }
    
}

$ary_files = array_combine(
    $ary_files,
    array_map( "filemtime", $ary_files )
);

arsort( $ary_files );

$str_latest_file = key( $ary_files );

echo "file:".$str_latest_file."\n";
echo "time:".$ary_files[key( $ary_files )];
```

Comment: Hola amigo y como puedo implementarlo en mi codigo anteriormente publicado en mi pregunta .

Comment: @AlbertoCruz a ver la idea de ser programador es que adquieras la capacidad de hacer la integracion logica del codigo por tu cuenta. aqui en el sitio podemos apoyarte con ejemplos o con algun error o problema puntual... que tengas, pero no hacemos tareas o trabajos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar scandir.

Obtienes los ficheros del directorio y usas SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING, entonces se ordenará alfabéticamente en sentido descendente.

Seleccionas el primero resultado de la array y ahí tienes el nombre del fichero :)!

https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.scandir.php

Suerte.